# C# and WPF: controls inaccessible from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, scope, visual-studio-express

I just started fiddling around with C# and WPF.

Let's say that I want to instantiate a Black grid and that I want to randomly move around a red square in said Grid.

Currently I can basically do whatever I want as long as I keep everything in "MainWindow.xaml.cs"...

Now, my problem is that if I create a new class (e.g., "MakeStuffHappen.cs") and from it I try to access the Grid (named "MyGrid") that will be instantiated by MainWindow's constructor, intellisense doesn't "see" it.
I tried making a getter that returns "MyGrid" but then the compiler says that "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ProjectName.MainWindow.getGrid()'.
Obviously I cannot define MainWindow as a static class...

Any tips on how to solve this?

Thanks!

P.S. Since I'm evidently no programmer I'm not necessarily aware of the technical terms to use when looking up information... so I apologize in advance if this question has been already asked.

P.P.S. I saw this: [Access MainWIndow Control from a class in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632827/access-mainwindow-control-from-a-class-in-a-separate-file) but it doesn't help.

Comment: With this level of knowledge I guess you'd be better off reading a C#  tutorial before getting to actual coding.

Comment: You can make a static instance of your control in MainWindow.cs and call it like MainWindow.yourControl

Comment: @Sybren Why would you *ever* make a static member to a UI class? Why not just pass the instance in when creating it, and then call a public method?

Comment: Consider starting a storyboard via a public method. If the movement has to be random *still* start it via a public method, and then handle it in `MainWindow`, not `MakeStuffHappen`.

Comment: @Gebb: while what you're saying is definitely true, I'd have appreciated you mentioning either a specific C# topic or a general OOP concept to look up. But thanks anyway. I'll do that and also try what the other suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Once your view is initialized (when the OnInitialized event fires) you can pass the initialized Grid into your helper class:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainWindow 
{
    MakeStuffHappen helper = null;
    public MainWindow()
    { 
       OnInitialized += (s,e)=> { helper = new MakeStuffHappen(this.MyGridName); } 
    }
}
```

**MakeStuffHappen.cs**

```
public class MakeStuffHappen
{
    Grid theGrid = null;
    public MakeStuffHappen(Grid grid)
    {
        theGrid = grid;
        // Do stuff with the grid.
    }
}
```